# Is it possible to hunt crocodiles using blades?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

For many animals in the wild, my technique is to climb a tree and air assassinate them as they walk underneath, or hide in a bush and whistle them over to ambush them. However, I don't seem to be able to engage a crocodile with blades. I am only having success targeting and killing them with firearms. I have only tried a few times, so it could be a camera or targeting problem... has anyone had success?

Comment: Yeah, I've been wondering that. After fighting them off I've been chasing after them with my swords and kind of disappointed that I can't enstabinate them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not been able to kill crocodiles with any form of blades either, not even with air assassination. Assuming it's not a bug, crocodiles can only be killed with firearms or the blowpipe, just like monkeys.

Interestingly, it appears monkeys and crocodiles can't be killed with throwing knives either.

Answer (score -1):

I havent been able to hit them with blades either I believe it might be caused by crocodiles tough skin but that should make it so the blow dart dosent affect it